# initFormat doesn't join the string correctly on my code

Tags: javascript, gjs

I'm studying GCampax Gtk+Gjs example[1], and wondering how to use initFormat.

AFAIK it is a JS functionality to put together strings and variables, working such as

```
print("Hello, {0}".format("World"));  //--> Hello, World
```

but it seem that doesn't work this way in GJS:

```
const pkg = imports.package
pkg.initFormat()
print("Hello,{0}".format("World"))  //--> Hello,{0}
```

I expect Hello, World to be printed but I get Hello,{0} instead.

Help

[1] https://github.com/gcampax/gtk-js-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initFormat()` adds a `format()` method to strings. The formats work like in C and other languages derived from C's `printf` format language, so you would need to write `"Hello, %s".format("World")`.

However, this feature is obsolete since JS has interpolated strings. Just write something like this instead:

```
const target = "World";
print(`Hello, ${target}`);
```